# How to list commits unique to a branch using Dulwich

Tags: dulwich

If I have two release branches v1.25 and v1.25-SOC how to I get commits only in v1.250-SOC and I want to do this for every branch (get only branch specific commits in git). I use dulwich python library.

Main idea is I want to find commits which are first committed to the given branch. If these commits are there in later release versions its ok as long as those are not in older release versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the commits that are in one branch but not the other by using the revision graph Walker:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
r = Repo('.')
for entry in r.get_walker(include=[r['refs/heads/branch1'].id], exclude=[r['refs/heads/branch2'].id]):
     print entry.commit.id
```